# how to mock e.preventdefault in angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing

HTML file

```html
<input type="number" min="10" max="100" (keydown)="checkLength1($event,inputNumber)"#inputNumber/>
```

ts file

```js
  checkLength1(e: { key: string | number; keyCode: number; preventDefault: () => void; }, input: { value: string; }) {
    const keyValue = +e.key; const numberOnlyPattern = '[0-9]+';
    const newValue = input.value + (isNaN(keyValue) ? '' : keyValue.toString());
    const match = newValue.match(numberOnlyPattern);
    if (+newValue > 12 || !match || newValue === '') {e.preventDefault();} }
```

spec file

```js
   it("checkLength1", () => { const e ={ key: "1", keyCode: 1, preventDefault : () => void }
    const input = {value:"1" }
   component.onKeyPressHours(e, input); });
```

I am trying to write test cases for "checkLength1" method. But I am getting an error while constructing object for parameter "e". Please help me to resolve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `void` with `null`.

```js
it("checkLength1", () => { 
  const e = { key: "1", keyCode: 1, preventDefault : () => null };
  ...
```